# Stopping my camera from getting to close

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

This is my script (written in JavaScript), which creates a camera movement. I can't figure out how to make it so that I can get it to not move too close to the object (target). It is probably something simple, but I'm a noob at Unity.

If it's not possible to get it by modifying the existing code, could you suggest another way to get the desired motion?

```
#pragma strict
var target : Transform;
var localOffset = Vector3(0,0,0);
var finalPos : Vector3;
var currentPos : Vector3;
var speed = 0.01;
private var startTime: float;
private var journeyLength: float;

function Start() {
    startTime = Time.time;
}

function Update () {
    currentPos = transform.position;
    finalPos = target.position + (target.up * localOffset.z);
    finalPos = target.position + (target.forward * localOffset.x);
    transform.LookAt(target.position);

    journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, finalPos);
    var distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
    var fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, finalPos, fracJourney);
}
```

Comment: Maybe look up Unity's clamp method... It may be what you are after

Comment: that's not javascript, it's unityscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Vector3.Distance](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html)

```
function Update() 
{

...

if (Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position) > 10) // Change '10' to any distance that you want as a minimum
{
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, finalPos, fracJourney);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a small bug in your code, if you replace:

```
finalPos = target.position + (target.up * localOffset.z);
finalPos = target.position + (target.forward * localOffset.x);
```

with:

```
finalPos = target.position + (target.up * localOffset.z);
finalPos += (target.forward * localOffset.x);
```

will you get what you want?